# How to return a message upon receiving it

Tags: java, android, inputstream

I have a method called Receive , which starts a thread to receive message from a socket . as long as the socket is open I would like it to receive messages and return it to whoever called the method

```
public Message Receive(int numBytes)  {
    Thread receive =new Thread(new ReceiveMessage(numBytes));
    receive.start();
    return receivedMessage;

}
```

The received message is handled with a handler .

my problem is that this method returns null all the time until a real message is received through the inputstream , and I don't want that. 
I want that only when a real message is received the return line will be activated .

How do I do that?

Comment: Should thread continue running after first message is received and returned from the function? Who is going to receive the second and following messages?

Comment: You shouldn't call this method until the message is received. If at all, keep your thread running, and whenever a message is received (however you handle that) - call this method, but keep in mind that the response will be returned to the thread, and the thread needs to return it to the caller...

Comment: What you want is impossible. The result of the thread is much later availeble than that return statement of that function is executed. You should rethink your design. Better:  If the thread has received a message the thread can start a handler or method to send the message back.